# How do I create a new font from an existing font?

Tags: java, fonts, swt

In SWT, how can I create a bold/italic variant of a font and how can I scale a font? I tried

```
int fontStyle = SWT.BOLD;
int height = 1200;

FontData[] fds = font.getFontData ();
for (FontData fd: fds)
{
    fd.setStyle (fontStyle);
    fd.setHeight ((fd.getHeight () * height + 500) / 1000);
}
newFont = new Font(font.getDevice (), fds);
```

but that doesn't work for "Andale Mono", for example.

Comment: You get very little help in this question because you didn't add the JAVA tag to it.

Comment: You should, either, post a complete code, with the imports and a main (also called SSCCE - sscce.org)

Answer (score 0):

Not all fonts support Italic or Bold. You can set size of the font when creating it:

Font font = new Font(fontFamilyName, fontStyle, fontSize);

Comment: But why does it work when I use `new Font(device, "Andale Mono", SWT.BOLD)`? It just fails when I use the FontData API directly. I also can't see a difference when I call `fd.toString()`. Everything looks ok, I get different font handles but they look wrong on the screen.